# How to custom serialize in Spring when you dont have an Entity

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a Spring boot+ MongoDB project. This project returns a list of buildings ("centers"). But Spring puts the data inside a property.
This is my Get method:

```
    @GetMapping("/centros")
    public List<JsonNode> getCentros() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return centrosService.getCentros();
    }
```

and something like this is returned:

```
{"List":[
    {centro1},
    {centro2},
    ...
  ]
}
```

What I want it to return is the aray directly without the root node:

```
[
    {centro1},
    {centro2},
    ...
]
```

Another option that would also work for me is to be able to customize the rootname:

```
{"MyCustomRootName":[
    {centro1},
    {centro2},
    ...
  ]
}
```

I have found some interesting articles on stackoverflow, the problem is that they do not serve me because in the first place I have no Entity to map to. In other words, there is no "Centros" class. I am working directly with the JsonNode class.
So what I need to discover, is how I can remove or customize the Root Node using a Custom Serializer and then register it in Spring. I don't know how to register it, since since I don't have a "Centers" entity, I don't have where to use the annotations.

I'm trying to do a configuration class, but I'm not sure how to proceed. This is what I have so far:

```
package com.envira.gijonin.centros.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

public class JsonNodeCustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<JsonNode>{
    
    
    public JsonNodeCustomSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }
  
    public JsonNodeCustomSerializer(Class<JsonNode> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(JsonNode value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        
        gen.writeStartObject();
        provider.defaultSerializeField("centros", value, gen);
        // provider.defaultSerializeField("", value, gen);
        gen.writeEndObject();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Security-wise, it is much better to have a return value in the format of a property and not as an array.

Comment: That could also help me, but since Spring defaults to the name of the class you return, I haven't found a way to modify that name manually. That is, by default it returns "List" if I return a list. If I could change it to "centers" it would be fine. But I can't either.